# Query to get multiple values having hyphen from single node -Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

So far,Query I tried

```
{
    "query": {
    "constant_score": {
    "filter": {
    "terms": {
        "website_alias": [
            "chinajianghai.com",
            "perlong.com",
            "kasogroup.com",
            "kndmed.com",
            "medicalequipment-msl.com"
         ]
     }
   }
 }
}
}
```

I got only four results "chinajianghai.com", "perlong.com", "kasogroup.com", "kndmed.com" except "medicalequipment-msl.com". Because the last value having hyphen. How can i rectify this issue?

Comment: Could you try escaping the hyphen with a backslash?

Comment: If i put "medicalequipment\-msl.com" like this, showing error like "Unexpected number in JSON"

Answer (score 0):

try change 'website_alias' to 'website_alias.keyword'?

Comment: Hi, No results for 'website_alias.keyword'.